# How to trigger azure load test from azure dev-ops release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jmeter

I am able to CREATE and then RUN a new Azure Load test from Azure Dev-Ops Release pipeline.

I followed below article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/load-testing/tutorial-cicd-azure-pipelines

But it creates a new Test even if a test of same name already exists.

How do I trigger **EXISTING** load test with OR without passing CSV and other config files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I test the Azure Load test, currently there is no option to trigger existing load test or without passing CSV and other config files.

You could use "Request a feature" on the left side of [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to open a new suggestion ticket.